# Float moves everything to the one side, HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, web

I have a problem with an image and 'float: right;'. It moves everything on the image.
I really need help. I am just a beginner. Any help will be appreciated. Please help me.
My HTML code:

```
    <section id="header">
        <div class="container">
            <img scr="./img/logo.png" class="logo">

            <div class="header-text">
                <h1>Choose the cheapest teachers</h1>
                <span class="square"></span>
                <p>Here you can find the best people<br>Start working for us right now</p>
                <button class="common-btn">Read more</button>

                
            </div>
        </div>
```

My CSS code:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font: Nunito;
}

#header {
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(img/image3.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 80vh;
    height: 80vh;
    padding:35px;
    float: right;
}
    


}
.conatiner {
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.logo {
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    
}
.header-text{
    max-width: 350px;
    margin-top: 140px;
}
```

Comment: is it the image you wish to `float` to the right?

Comment: I would like to have this image on the right side but with this image, all other things move to the right side.

Comment: look at this https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_layout_float

Comment: Thank you but I will also like to get an answer for my current question

Comment: My goal is to have an image on the right side and text on the left side.

Comment: background-image: url(img/image3.png); here is a normal image and I want it to be on the right side

Comment: But when I give float: right; it moves everything on the right, I would like to separate it or do something like this

Comment: add a fixed height to the image and float right.

Comment: Could you explain me it more and write this code because I don't quite get it

Comment: you have several typos in the above css and `vh` cannot be used for widths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font: Nunito;
}

#header {
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(img/image3.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80vh;
    padding:35px;
    
}
    
img.logo{
    float: right!important;
}
.container {
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
}
.logo {
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 100px;
}
.header-text{
    max-width: 350px;
    margin-top: 140px;
}
```

```html
<section id="header">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" class="logo">

        <div class="header-text">
            <h1>Choose the cheapest teachers</h1>
            <span class="square"></span>
            <p>Here you can find the best people<br>Start working for us right now</p>
            <button class="common-btn">Read more</button>

            
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `css` file to match the following

```
.logo {
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px; /* Add a fixed height on image */
  float: right; /* then you can now float right */
}
```